# Text Emoticon HTML encoding not displaying correctly

Tags: html, encoding

I am making a static webpage.
I need to display the following text emoticons:

- ¯\__(ツ)_/¯
- (ง ͠° ͟ل͜ ͡°)ง
- (◕‿◕)
- (╥_╥)'
- ヾ(⌐■_■)ノ♪
- (ノಠ益ಠ)ノ彡┻━┻
- (ﾉ◕ヮ◕)ﾉ*:･ﾟ✧

However, they are instead displayed as:

- Â¯*(ãƒ„)*/Â¯
- (à¸‡ Í Â° ÍŸÙ„Íœ Í¡Â°)à¸‡
- (â—•â€¿â—•)
- (â•¥_â•¥)
- ãƒ¾(âŒâ– _â– )ãƒŽâ™ª
- (ãƒŽà² ç›Šà² )ãƒŽå½¡â”»â”â”»
- (ï¾‰â—•ãƒ®â—•)ï¾‰*:ï½¥ï¾Ÿâœ§

I have the UTF-8 tag in my html document (in head). The tag is the following:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

The weird thing is that this works locally (ie, the text emoticons are displayed correctly), but it only breaks when I put it on my server.

Any idea what to do?

Comment: This is only a wild guess, but does your server save the file in utf-8 too? The file format is important too. Or anything related to file-saving/file format settings that could be off when putting in the server, if at all possible that it's getting modified.

Comment: You might having server declare different HTTP encoding in header, and according to W3C it has a higher precedence over document encoding. [link](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations.en)

Comment: Show us the response headers from your server.  There's not enough information in your post to diagnose this.

Comment: @Forty You were right. I checked my JS file (which contains these text emoticons) and they were encoded improperly (as shown at the bottom). Is there any other way to create these text emoticons?

Comment: @Brad  I will let you know the info when i get home

Answer (score 0):

To me, the fact that you can have it displayed locally in browser means something wrong with your servers HTTP header. You should be able to check the header inside your browser development tool, or Fiddler.

Another thing you could try is declare charset in your reference in JS file.

```
<script src="app.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"/>
```